# Mapbox - Calculate if MGLPointAnnotation is within an MGLPolygon

Tags: ios, mapbox

In my iOS app, I have manually drawn / mapped a shape / polygon and added it as a subView to my mapView.

From pre-existing data points, the user can then drop a number of MGLPointAnnotations onto the same map. These all appear. I can title / subtitle them, and add the appropriate delegate methods to be able to click on them.

How can I calculate if an MGLPointAnnotation is contained within the "borders" of the MGLPolygon (or MGLShape, if this is better)?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`MGLCoordinateInCoordinateBounds(coordinate:bounds:)`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Geometry.html#/c:MGLGeometry.h@F@MGLCoordinateInCoordinateBounds) to check if a given `coordinate` is within [`MGLPolygon.overlayBounds`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Protocols/MGLOverlay.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLOverlay(py)overlayBounds).

Comment: Thanks @friedbunny. I may try this to see how well it performs. I managed to find another published example on the Mapbox website that I was directed towards using `visibleFeatures(at: styleLayerIdentifiers:)` which I have started testing and does work, though for my purposes there is some effort involved to ensure the coordinates in question are in the mapView...

Answer (score 0):

I was directed towards using the `visibleFeatures(at: styleLayerIdentifiers:)` method, which does seem to work as I outlined. The "limitation" (specifically for my own purposes) is that this works only when the coordinates in question are on screen / visible within the current mapView. For example, with dropped pins / annotations = perfect. I will likely be loading coordinates in from an external data source and originally hadn't realised this need. I may be able to code around it, if not I will investigate @friedbunny's solution.